# Дублировать четные элементы двусвязного списка С#

Tags: c#, list, linked-list, двусвязный-список

У меня есть двусвязный список из чисел {1, 2, 6, 7, 9}.Мне необходимо продублировать все чётные элементы = {1, 2, 2, 6, 6, 7, 9}. Как я могу это сделать с помощью с#?

Comment: Нашел баг, поправил ответ. Если он оказалася полезен, отметьте его галочкой.

Comment: Да, я присоединяюсь к совету - отметьте галочкой, очень хороший ответ!

Comment: Врёте, нет у вас двусвязного списка. Какой именно класс используете? Как заполняете? Как пытаетесь продублировать элементы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы редактировать ноды списка, надо и цикл прогонять по нодам, а не по значениям.

Я взял пример из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netframework-4.8) и доработал под вашу задачу.

```cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    LinkedList<int> list = new LinkedList<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 6, 7, 9 });
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", list));

    LinkedListNode<int> node = list.First;
    while (node != null)
    {
        if (node.Value % 2 == 0)
            list.AddBefore(node, new LinkedListNode<int>(node.Value));
        node = node.Next;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", list));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
1 2 6 7 9
1 2 2 6 6 7 9
```

---

Для любителей `Linq`.

Если добавить вот такой экстеншн

```cs
public static class LinkedListExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<T>> EnumerateNodes<T>(this LinkedList<T> list)
    {
        for (LinkedListNode<T> node = list.First; node != null; node = node.Next)
            yield return node;
    }
}
```

Тогда можно будет записать так

```cs
list.EnumerateNodes()
    .Where(node => node.Value % 2 == 0)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(node => list.AddBefore(node, new LinkedListNode<int>(node.Value)));
```

или так

```cs
foreach (LinkedListNode<int> node in list.EnumerateNodes().Where(node => node.Value % 2 == 0))
{
    list.AddBefore(node, new LinkedListNode<int>(node.Value));
}
```

Comment: Круто! Попытался сделать то же самое при помощи LINQ - что то не получилось...

Comment: @S.H. дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо. Очень красивое решение. Вот как раз до того, чтобы написать extension method - я и не догадался

Comment: Решение с ToList.ForEach — так себе, в прод лучше не тащить ;)

Comment: @АндрейNOP верно :)